# FileUpload control: How to put back removed files when file removal fails on the server

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I recently discovered the PrimeVue library which can be used in VueJS applications which require a series of basic controls (grids, tables, components, etc.). My question pertains to the usage of the FileUpload component.

I have a scenario where I have 2 endpoint URLs: one to respond to file uploads, and another to respond to file removals. When a user makes a file selection, the file is uploaded immediately.

When a user wants to remove a file they have uploaded, I need to call the 2nd endpoint method for this. The problem I am faced with is, in the event the file removal fails on the server, I want the file not to be removed from the FileUpload component on my page. Currently, the file is removed, regardless of the result of my file removal endpoint. How do I make the PrimeVue file upload control more aware of failures when the file removal endpoint fails? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<FileUpload
            name="fileUploadName"
            :auto="true"
            class="p-fileupload-advanced"
            :max-file-size="3e+6"
            invalid-file-limit-message="You cannot upload more than 10 files"
            invalid-file-size-message="A file may not exceed 3MB in size"
            invalid-file-type-message="Only images and documents are accepted"
            :file-limit="10"
            choose-label="Select Files"
            cancel-label="Cancel"
            :multiple="true"
            ref="fileUpload"
            @progress="handleFileUploadProgress"
            @removeUploadedFile="handleRemoveUploadedFileEvent"
            :url="fileHandlingService.getFileUploadUrl()"
            :with-credentials="true"
            @error="handleFileUploadErrorEvent"
            @upload="handleFileUploadCompleteEvent"
        >
          <template #empty>
            <p class="is-text has-text-centered">You may drag and drop files here to upload</p>
          </template>
        </FileUpload>
```

According to the documentation (https://primevue.org/fileupload/#advanced), I thought that I need to listen to the @removeUploadedFile event - this would give me access to the file that got removed, together with the remaining files:

```
const handleRemoveUploadedFileEvent = async (event: FileUploadRemoveUploadedFile) => {
  state.hasErrors = false;
  state.errorMessage = undefined;
  const response = await fileHandlingService.removeUploadedFile(event.file);
  if (response.didError) {
    state.hasErrors = true;
    state.errorMessage = response.message;
    return;
  }
  state.fileIds = state.fileIds.filter((item) => item !== response.model!);
}
```

It almost feels like I need a way to manipulate the state of the FileUpload control. This would let me put back the removed file onto the list of uploaded files.

I hope my question is clear. How can I "put back" the removed uploaded file on the FileUpload control, in the event file removal fails on the server (for whatever reason)?